# Determine the individual unicode characters that make up a word

Tags: unicode

I'm having trouble breaking a word into its individual unicode components. I'm working with the devanagari script using google input tools. An example is र्म (pronounced -rm), which I want to break into म (-m) and the that hook at the top (-r). But I can't seem to find the unicode character that corresponds to the hook at the top. Here's some of the solutions I tried
1. copy and past र्म into MS word and hit alt x. But this breaks the word into र् and म. It doesn't give me the unicode character for the top hook
2. I tried the site http://shapecatcher.com/. I found a character called latin egyptological ain; while similar in shape, it cannot be used on top of another character. I'm looking the conjunct version of the hook.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using TekMaker on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

The ‘hook at the top’ representing a preceding `र्` is an inseparable part of the glyph for a variety of biconsonantal ligatures. It's not a discrete, freely-combinable diacritical mark as we would understand it in Latin-like scripts.

Consequently the visual rendering element doesn't have its own Unicode representation distinct from its linguistic meaning `र्`, sorry!